# Is there a name for symmetry in which fermions and bosons are in identical adjoint representations?

Tags: terminology, supersymmetry, representation-theory, group-representations, yang-mills

In a Yang-Mills theory, with gauge group $G$, if the Fermions are in an adjoint representation then for every Fermion with "charge" $Q$ there is a boson with charge $Q$. i.e. there is no difference between charges on fermions and bosons.

This is different for example to chromodynamics $SU(3)$ where the bosons are in the matrix representation and the fermions are in a complex vector representation. So there is no "red" gluon and no "red-antigreen" quark.

As an extreme example an $E_8$ GUT would have 248 types of bosons and act on 248 types of fermions in the adjoint representation.

Is there a name for this type of symmetry? (Is it necessarily super-symmetry? The theory might still not be supersymmetric.)

Can the Universe exhibit this symmetry?

Comment: Well, the theory could be made supersymmetric, if you tweaked the couplings. That is, your condition is necessary for gauge supermultiplets, but not sufficient. Conversely, you might start with susy-QCD, and add extra color singlet (nonrenormalizable) powers of fermion bilinears which spoil susy but are still color gauge invariant. It has been found, in the late 70s that the susy couplings are IR attractors of most of these theories.

Comment: So, would a theory that had this symmetry but not full supersymmetry be at all interesting or useful? I mean postulating this symmetry does predict extra particles too. How would you define this symmetry exactly? I'm tempted to call it "charge democracy".

Comment: Yes, in the extreme, cf [Curtright-Ghandour 1978](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0003-4916(78)80001-3). I'd define it as "potential busy". It's standard lore.

Comment: Potentially supersymmetric. Spellchecker....